# How to iterate by query results and send it to template

Tags: python, django

I want to get random words from the database and create flashcards with them. For this moment I get a record from the database, send it to the template, and check if user's answer is correct. Look at the below code.

In the end result, I want to rand 10 words and send it to the template (maybe in for loop) and after answer send information if it was correct (after each word). But I don't know how can I do it with store information in the `learn()` function about correct and wrong answers.

**learn.html**

```
    {% block content %}
    {% if not result %}
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <div class="card w-75 bg-light mb-3">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="d-flex flex-row-reverse">English - vocabulery</h5>
                    <p class="d-flex flex-row-reverse">more information</p>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="font-weight-bold" for="exampleFormControlInput1">{{word}}</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="wordAnswer" id="wordInput"translation placeholder="word translation">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="font-weight-bold" for="exampleFormControlInput1">{{example}}</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="exampleAnswer" id="wordInput"translation placeholder="example translation">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="POST">Check</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    {% else %}
        Not correct answer
    {% endif %}
 {% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
def learn(request):

    words = Word.objects.get(id=1)
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        answer = request.POST['wordAnswer']
        if answer == words.translation:
            return render(request, 'learn.html', {
                'result': True,
                })
    return render(request, 'learn.html', {
        'words': words,
        'result': False,
    })
```

**EDIT**

```
class Word(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    translation = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    example = models.TextField()
    example_translation = models.TextField()
    status = models.IntegerField()
    category = models.ManyToManyField('Category', related_name='word_type')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.word
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 {% if not result %}
{% for word in words %}
        <form action="/learn/" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}    
            <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <div class="card w-75 bg-light mb-3">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="d-flex flex-row-reverse">English - vocabulery</h5>
                    <p class="d-flex flex-row-reverse">more information</p>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="font-weight-bold" for="exampleFormControlInput1">{{word}}</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="wordAnswer" id="wordInput"translation placeholder="word translation">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="font-weight-bold" for="exampleFormControlInput1">{{example}}</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="exampleAnswer" id="wordInput"translation placeholder="example translation">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="POST">Check</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
{% endfor %}

    {% else %}
        Not correct answer
    {% endif %}
 {% endblock %}
```

views:

```
import random

def learn(request):

    words = Word.objects.get(id=1)

    random_items = random.sample(words, 10) #This gives you 10 random objects
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        answer = request.POST['wordAnswer']
        if answer == words.translation:
            return render(request, 'learn.html', {
                'result': True,
                })
    return render(request, 'learn.html', {
        'random_items': words,
        'result': False,
    })
```

Did not test it, maybe it will help you

Comment: I said, that I want to show one card with a word and after answer an check if it's correct, show next. You add an example, where all cards with words are showing on template, but I don't want to implement it as you show.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to explain what i did with comments in the codes. My English skills is not good, if I did mistake in my sentences, sorry about that :) I think this will help you.

learn.html :

```
    {% block content %}
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <div class="card w-75 bg-light mb-3">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="d-flex flex-row-reverse">English - vocabulery</h5>
                    <p class="d-flex flex-row-reverse">more information</p>
                    {% if result is None %}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="font-weight-bold" for="answerControlInput{{word}}">{{word}}</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="answer" id="answerControlInput{{word}}" placeholder="word translation">
                            <input style="display:none;" name="answeredWord" value="{{word.pk}}">
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                        {{ answeredWord }} <br>
                        {{ result }}
                    {% endif %}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="POST">Check</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
 {% endblock %}
```

views.py:

```py
def learn(request):

    randomWord = Word.objects.all().order_by("?")[:1] # this will return 1 random word
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        answeredWordPk = request.POST["answeredWord"]
        answeredWord = Word.objects.get(pk = answeredWordPk)
        answer = request.POST["answer"]
        if answer == answeredWord.translation:
            return render(request, "learn.html", {
                "answeredWord" : answeredWord,
                "result" : True
            })
        else:
            return render(request, "learn.html", {
                "answeredWord" : answeredWord,
                "result" : False
            })
    return render(request, 'learn.html', {
        'randomWord': randomWord
    })
```

Comment: Is your problem not solved? I spent about half an hour on this and after testing my solution, I shared it. I would expect you to make any comeback.

Comment: Hi, sorry that you have to wait for my response. I tried to use the code that you posted, but it does not work. Words rand is ok and returns 10 random words. But learn template nothing show. I tried to find the issue and it looks like it's not going to for loop in the template, but I don't understand why, because I checked and in view.py words, list is not empty.

Comment: Please add your Word model to your question

Comment: Thank you. And i need one more thing. Please explain the purpose of `example` and `example_translation` fields. I want to correctly understand, what do you want :)

Comment: 'example' and 'example_translation' will be something as an example usage of 'word'. So if we have the word 'dog', the example will be 'This dog is calm'

Comment: Do you want example_translation input from user ? and you want check both of them ? word and example translations ?

Comment: Yes, exactly! But I asked only about check word translation because I thought that if I will have an example/tip how to implement it, I will do it for other fields ;)

Comment: Please check my answer carefully, or tell me if you get any error from this solution. Because, i am sure this must be help to you :)

Comment: I analyzed code ~30 minutes and I found that you added space in 'wrods ' :/ But unnecessary, your answer isn't resolve my issue... I wrote, that I want to show one word to answer and after click 'check' button, show information if it's correct, and present next one question. Your answer works the same as code HermanTheGerman....

Comment: Omg :) I got you wrong sorry. I'll try again to tailor my answer to what you really want